# CustomInfoWindow GoogleMaps - boxDecoration

Tags: flutter, google-maps

i have problem.
I want to add borderRadius and color to my CustomInfoWindow (when user click on marker on map).

I prepared class to show Container with all info
**ContainerGoogleMaps**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:streeti/static/static_colors.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/bold_big_text.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/small_text.dart';

class ContainerGoogleMaps extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;

  ContainerGoogleMaps({required this.title, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and class who added markers to GoogleMaps
**MapScreen**

```
import 'package:custom_info_window/custom_info_window.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:streeti/pages/plate_withOTP_page.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/bold_big_text.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/bottom_nav.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/container_google_maps_info.dart';
import 'package:streeti/widgets/small_text.dart';

const LatLng consLocation = LatLng(48.355016218833654, 15.813391958051588);
const LatLng marker1 = LatLng(48.34161850665899, 15.778319914302879);
const LatLng marker2 = LatLng(48.32890042576883, 15.915319080569235);
const LatLng marker3 = LatLng(48.286968189915875, 15.841635818003887);
const LatLng marker4 = LatLng(48.26770643729367, 15.756396257371149);
const LatLng marker5 = LatLng(48.325018246453446, 15.70158482793595);

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};
  final _customInfoWindowController = CustomInfoWindowController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double redContainerHeight = screenHeight * 0.1;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  height: redContainerHeight,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          BoldBigText(
                            text: 'Suchen',
                            fontSize: 18,
                            isBold: true,
                          ),
                          SmallText(
                            text: "Top Betriebe",
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      const PlateWIthOTPPage(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                            child: Icon(Icons.search),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                //! Google maps
                Expanded(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          GoogleMap(
                            onMapCreated: (controller) {
                              _mapController = controller;
                              _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController =
                                  controller;
                              addMarker('test', marker1, 'AAA');
                              addMarker('test2', marker2, 'VVV');
                              addMarker('test3', marker3, 'CCCC');
                              addMarker('test4', marker4, 'AAA');
                              addMarker('test5', marker5, 'HJHJ');
                            },
                            onTap: (location) {
                              _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();
                            },
                            onCameraMove: (position) {
                              _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove!();
                            },
                            markers: _markers.values.toSet(),
                            initialCameraPosition:
                                CameraPosition(target: consLocation, zoom: 11),
                          ),
                          CustomInfoWindow(
                            controller: _customInfoWindowController,
                            height: 100,
                            width: 250,
                            offset: 50,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            //! bottomnav
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
                isNachrichtActive: false,
                isKarteActive: false,
                isCommunityActive: false,
                isProfilActive: false,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//!add markers
  addMarker(String id, LatLng location, String title) async {
    var markerIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(size: Size(50, 50)),
        'lib/assets/images/map_pin3.png');

    var marker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(id),
      position: location,
      icon: markerIcon,
      onTap: () {
        _customInfoWindowController.addInfoWindow!(
          ContainerGoogleMaps(
            title: title,
          ),
          location,
        );
      },
    );

    _markers[id] = marker;
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

the problem is that element CustomInfoWindow cannot be modify - I want to add border radius or maybe color transparent - that will be great .. ;)
But I don't have any idea to change this ...

Do you have some idea?
Screen bellow
[image: Screen form emulator]

Comment: You can do this with the [Advanced Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/advanced-markers/add-marker?hl=en), since you can use actual views to render as a marker which is pretty much customizable. But unfortunately, I looked through the `google_maps_flutter` package and it looks like it has not been released yet in flutter.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help - Thats the solutions for me ;)